# PYTHON pandas Is there a way to dynamically delete rows from pandas dataframe WHILE writing it to CSV to free memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several huge dataframes, and I'm writing multithreaded functions to write them to disk as .csv but it takes a really long time and I want that memory back so I can go get more huge dataframes while these slowly write.

Is it possible to use pandas to:

1. write a chunk
2. delete those rows fromt he dataframe to free memory
3. Repeat until dataframe is written to disk as csv and thread is finished

Comment: Relevant and a great read: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: This was super useful. The answer is "don't use pandas for this." I'm off to explore Dask. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure how this works under the hood - but assume that chunksize parameter might be what you are looking for.

[Pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)